# using the enterprise library cache application blocks in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, enterprise-library

I tried to use the cache application blocks of the microsoft enterprise library. I have used the MS Enterprise Library V5.0

Here is the sample code i have made, inside the home controller's index method.

```
        Person p = new Person(10, "person1");
        ICacheManager cacheMgr = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("myCache");
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        if (Session["currsession"] != null)
        {
            if (!cacheMgr.Contains(p.pid.ToString()))
            {
                Response.Write("item is not in cache");
                return View(p);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("item is still in cache");
                return View(p);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Session["currsession"] = 1;
            cacheMgr.Add(p.pid.ToString(), p, CacheItemPriority.High, null, new SlidingTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
            return View(cacheMgr.GetData(p.pid.ToString()));
        }
```

The person class i use in the model has just a constructor with 2 public properties. Nothing special features are used.

Now, is this the right procedure to use the caching of the enterprise library caching blocks. If not, how else can i code this block of code in an efficient manner.

Also, i get the response as `item is not in cache` only after 20 second delay. Is there any mistake in the implementation of the code or is there a theory behind the caching in detail.

Kindly suggest the best practice for this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify a sliding expiration of 10 seconds, that means that you will get `item is not in cache` if you wait more than 10 seconds between reloading the page.

Load first time in session => no message
Reload => in cache
Reload => in cache
Wait 10 seconds
Reload => not in cache

Is this what you're seeing?

---

Old answer:

The enterprise caching application block is probably way more than you need. My favorite cache is [FubuMVC](https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubumvc)'s Cache (just include FubuCore.dll). You can get a very similar implementation by using a ConcurrentDictionary with a "missing element" delegate. Here's an example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/37bbc361-6851-43db-9e90-80cc7e6ac15f

FubuMVC Cache example:

```
public class PersonCache
{
    private Cache _Cache = new Cache();

    public PersonCache()
    {
        _Cache.OnMissing = key => MyDatabase.People.GetById(key);
    }

    public Person GetById(int id)
    {
        return _Cache[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Please note that my query is how you maintain the cache between the multiple page refreshes in the same session. For this purpose, i have used a session variable. Is this the right way. Please analyze my code and leave me a reply.

Comment: Sorry I guess I never finished reading the question. It's 2am here so I'm not really focused.